# Single line scrolling HTML list

Tags: html, css

Using a list as;

```
<ul id="scroller">
    <li><img src="../static/image/brand1.png" title="brand title"></li>
    .....
</ul>
```

And with css properties;

```
    ul#scroller li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline;
    }

    ul#scroller li img{
        margin-left: 75px;
        float:left;
    }

    ul#scroller {
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

and the YUI CSS reset just before this definition.

The problem is; instead of the horizontal scroll, my list items are line breaking.

Peace

Comment: You mean like here, where you might get two rows of Beaker? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/YMDCw/

Comment: exactly, just add a couple more list items. they need to overflow 'horizontally' but they are linebreaking..

Comment: i would actually try setting float: left directly in the li, though I cannot see obvious reason for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add "white-space:nowrap;" to the ul#scroller element.

http://jsfiddle.net/YMDCw/7/

```
ul#scroller{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
ul#scroller li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

ul#scroller li img{
    margin-left: 75px;
}

ul#scroller {
    overflow: scroll;
}
​
```

Comment: @xatanian, Forcing the element not to wrap, isn't the perfect way

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the css like this?

```
ul {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    min-width: 800px;
}

img {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left !important;
}
```